# Where does dig additional section nameserver information come from?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dig, domain-registrar, glue-record

I have a client whose website has intermittent issues, which I believe are due to DNS lookup.  When this happens and they do a ping, the host cannot be resolved.  Therefore, I ran:

```
dig @a.gtld-servers.net autoquarterly.com
```

I get:

```
;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.hostlatch.com.  172800  IN  A   109.73.173.210
ns2.hostlatch.com.  172800  IN  A   109.73.173.211
```

but these are not the correct IP addresses.  If I do nslookup on the two nameservers, I get the correct IP addresses.

My question is where are these incorrect nameserver IP addresses coming from?  I was under the impression these were glue records which are registered with the domain registrar.  However, I noticed every domain I look up has the nameserver IP addresses in the ADDITIONAL section even though only domains which use a subdomain of their own domain name for their nameservers need glue records.

Comment: How could we possibly know? You didn't mention the domain.

Comment: In circumstances like this [you should disclose the actual domain name](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) if possible.

Comment: Okay, the domain is autoquarterly.com.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I checked the domain you gave and got similar results. You will want to change these entries yourself in your registrar's control panel, or if you really think this isn't your fault, you'll need to contact them to get them changed.

Comment: These are called glue records and they are maintained by your domain registrar. You should be able to change them using your domain registrar's admin site.

Comment: Okay that is what I thought, but what confuses me is that any small site I can think of has these.  Shouldn't only sites that maintain their own nameservers at their domain name have glue records?

Comment: Got it working.  Thank you for your help.  The issue was that hostlatch.com had a glue record for it's nameservers even though hostlatch.com does not use it's own nameservers.  The entry was wrong.  I guess a.gtld-servers.net finds the nameservers for autoquarterly.com and then goes and looks up their IPs in teh glue records for hostlatch.com.  I thought the additional section reported glue records from autoquarterly.com

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the glue records for hostlatch.com.  When I ran dig, the a.gtld-servers.net server found the nameserver names and then looked up their IP addresses in the glue records for hostlatch.com, not the glue records for autoquarterly.com or any other nameserver.  It was the glue records set by the hostlatch.com registrar that needed to be changed.